# MQTT on Azure IOT Hub : Error initializing MQTT connection:Not authorized to connect

Tags: java, azure, mqtt, iot, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to use Microsoft Azure IOT Hub to demonstrate connecting my device to IOT Hub and send messages using mqtt protocol.
I have an account and created device and SAS with TTL as required. I am using java client SDK given by microsoft azure to connect but my connection is not authorized.
I have followed all the steps as given in the below URL:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-mqtt-support/
Please help me in this regards. My logs are below:

Logs:

```
MqttIotHubConnection.open() connectionOptions=
============== Connection options ==============
CleanSession : false
SocketFactory : null
MqttVersion : 4
KeepAliveInterval : 20
ConTimeout : 30
UserName : PCSIOTHub.azure-devices.net/MQ...
SSLProperties : null
WillDestination : null


Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error initializing MQTT connection:Not authorized to connect
at com.microsoft.azure.iothub.transport.mqtt.MqttIotHubConnection.open(MqttIotHubConnection.java:142)
at com.microsoft.azure.iothub.transport.mqtt.MqttTransport.open(MqttTransport.java:83)
at com.microsoft.azure.iothub.DeviceClient.open(DeviceClient.java:163)
at samples.com.microsoft.azure.iothub.SendReceive.main(SendReceive.java:210)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Microsoft Java client for IoT Hub, you don't need to create the SAS token yourself, the SDK does it for you.

If you follow the example here, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted/#create-a-simulated-device-app, all you need to do is replace:

```
private static IotHubClientProtocol protocol = IotHubClientProtocol.AMQPS;
```

with:

```
private static IotHubClientProtocol protocol = IotHubClientProtocol.MQTT;
```

and you will have a basic Java client that can communicate with IoT Hub over MQTT.

Answer (score 1):

As @DominicBetts said, you don't need to create the SAS token when using the IoTHub SDK for Java. More explaination for the security of IoTHub, please see the offical document [`Azure IoT Hub developer guide`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-devguide/).

As reference as sample, you can refer to the [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/java/device/samples/send-event/src/main/java/samples/com/microsoft/azure/iothub/SendEvent.java) on GitHub to know how to send messages in the different protocols for Java.